# Dynamic way to take on the height of a container?

Tags: html, css

I have code with a link element nested within a parent element, resembling something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#" class="linkitem">Hello</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="linkitem">Hello</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="linkitem">Hello</a></li>
        <img src="img">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make it so the link takes on the height of navbar, which is determined by the height of the image and various margin/padding attributes. I want to do this so I can create some css that makes it so it appears that the entire background of the portion of the navbar where the link is is changing color when the link is hovered on, like so:

```
.navbar > li > a:hover {
background-color:red;
}
```

But as it stands now, only the small background of the text of the link is highlighted instead of the entire portion of the navbar that contains the link. I don't want to do `li:hover` because I only want the background to change color when the actual link text is selected. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried setting the height of the list item to 100%?

Comment: if you want to dynamically modify CSS based on dynamic values that are unknown to the DOM on load, you need to use javascript, I like jQuery: http://www.jquery4u.com/dynamic-css-2/change-css-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the fix is an easy one; simply apply `display:block;` to the anchor tags:

```
.navbar > li > a {
  display:block;   
}
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/DrTH9/

**Documentation**

- CSS `display` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#" class="linkitem">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="linkitem">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="linkitem" >Hello</a></li>
            <li class="imgItem">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50"  />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <style>
        .container,
        .navbar,
        .navbar li,
        .navbar li a
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .navbar{
            display: table;
        }
        .navbar li{
            display: table-cell;
            padding: 0 1em; /* you can have horizontal padding on these if you like */
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .navbar li.imgItem{
            padding: 0; /* Clear padding from image item */
        }
        .navbar li.hover,
        .navbar li:hover{
            background: red;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .navbar img{
            margin: -5px 0 0 0;
            top: 5px;
            position: relative;
            /* 
                This fixes a weird bug where the table puts 5px on the bottom of an image that defines a cell's height. 
                NO idea why this is. You may need to mess with this.
            */
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```